# Aws extract tar.gz on S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

As i'm New on aws and a little confused by all the similar services, I would like to have some leads and know if I am in the right direction.

I have tar.gz archives stored on aws s3 glacier deep archives. I would like that when requesting a restore, the archive is automatically extracted and the folders and files it contains put in s3 (with an expiration date).

these archives are too big to be extracted via lambda (300GB or more).

My idea would be to trigger a lambda function when the restore is complete and use that lambda function to start another aws service that does the extraction. I was thinking either aws batch or fargate. Which service do you think is the most suitable? For this kind of simple task it is preferable to use an arm architecture?
If someone has already done this before and has codes to share I'm interested (if not I'll try to put my final solution here for others).

Comment: AWS Batch and Fargate are not exclusive. AWS Batch jobs can either be executed on EC2 machines or on Fargate containers. AWS Batch would be a perfectly fine solution for your problem.

Comment: I am not really sure. If you are to use Fargate for the extraction, Should you mount an EFS volume to the Fargate service and extract the archives there, or is it possible to extract inside the docker image. any idea?

Comment: You could use AWS Lambda by attaching an AWS EFS filesystem. The trick is knowing when the restored file is available to do the extraction. This might best be done with an AWS Step Functions loop.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.